# Hot to declare an empty Map/dictionary?

Tags: f#

I would like to initialize a recursive function with a Map. To declare a read-only dictionary with value we can do:

```fs
let dictionary1  = dict [ (1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c") ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcyxCsIwFIXhPU9xyJRADVY3xamjboIO4lDbWwikuZDEoUifPYbg4vYdDvxT3AwcKGdHCaMdkmXfh6UFTnXiAdU2kL3UR6hd0atqXzRIjacQEweQoxnW/xVGFgCuS0w0m459ZEfmHmyii/Wk5JmWAz7bFbfevamwXWVTS6ZcP9VPI@cv)

Now, I would like to create an empty dictionary. How to achieve that?

I am looking fo something like:

```fs
let dictionary1 = {} // <- ok this is js
let (stuff, dictionary2) = parseRec("whatever", dictionary1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
let dictionary1  = dict []

for elem in dictionary1 do
   printfn "Key: %d Value: %s" elem.Key elem.Value
```

and that gives you an empty dictionary.

The `printfn` usage reveals to the type inference engine the correct types of key and value.

If you want to be explicit then you can specify the types in several ways:

```
let dictionary1 = dict Seq.empty<int * string>
let dictionary1 = dict ([] : (int * string) list)
let dictionary1 = dict [] : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int, string>
let dictionary1 : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int, string> = dict []
```

Comment: `dict Seq.empty<int * string>` and ` dict ([] : (int * string) list)` could be seen as `(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>).ToDictionary()` in C# world, couldnt they?

Comment: Well, the type of `dict` is `seq<'K * 'V>  -> System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<'K,'V>` so any tuple sequence can be used to generate a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Since you ask for Map/Dictionary, here is two other solutions for [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-class-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
let dictionary1 : Map<int, string> = Map.empty
let dictionary1 = Map<int, string> []
```

[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sets_and_Maps)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a .NET `Dictionary`, you can use a .net `Dictionary`:

```
let dictionary1 = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>()
```

Comment: F#'s `Map` is not a `Dictionary`, it's a distinct immutable map implementation. This is why, for example, `Map.add` returns a new `Map` object. As in, ["An immutable dictionary of elements. Elements are accessed by key."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-collection-types)